# how to authenticate in interactive server render mode?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, mudblazor

I'm currently making a web app using blazor and mudblazor and I'm having issue with how to login my user because everywhere I look I'm being told to use HttpContext.SignInAsync to do such thing but I can't because my app is in interactive server render mode for mudblazor.

I tried to look into signalR that seems to be the official way in interactive mode but from what I saw it requires a webassembly projet but mine is a web app.
I also tried Looking into the official Microsoft documentation, they say : "For scenarios where the HttpContext is required in interactive components, we recommend flowing the data via persistent component state from the server.", but I can't understand what they mean by that and they don't give example that I think apply to my situation.

Comment: What type of Authentication?

Comment: I'm using cookie authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You could add controller in Blazor web app (InterActiveServer) to access httpcontext for login to cookie. Try following:
Create a "Controllers" folder in project root and add `AuthenticateController`

```
    public class AuthenticateController : Controller
    {
        [Route("/authenticate")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromQuery]string usr, [FromQuery]string pwd)
        {
            if (usr == "admin" && pwd == "123")
            {
                var userClaims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usr),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "aa@test.com"),
                };

                var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims,"auth1");
                var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync("auth1", userPrincipal);
                return Redirect("/counter");
            }            

            return Redirect("/");
        }

        [Route("/logout")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
```

program.cs

```
...
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("auth1")
                .AddCookie("auth1");
...
app.MapControllers();
```

Then you have can navigate to this url `https://localhost:xxxx/Authenticate?usr=admin&pwd=123` to login from "front-end" components.